# GrailsDataBinder limitation?

Tags: grails, data-binding

I'm trying to use grails data binding to map some form parameters into my model, but I think perhaps there are some limitations regarding mapping embedded collections.

For instance, if I'm submitting some parameters like this then the mapping works fine:

```
//this works
productLineItems[0].product.id='123'
productLineItems[0].name='product name'
productLineItems[0].description='some description'
...
```

However, if my `productLineItems` collection is embedded within an association of the domain class I'm trying to save then `GrailsDataBinder` blows up with an `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.exceptions.InvalidPropertyException`:

```
//this blows up
sale.productLineItems[0].product.id='123'
sale.productLineItems[0].name='product name'
sale.productLineItems[0].description='some description'
...
```

I'd really like to avoid having to do the mapping by hand. Is there a way around this?

I'm using Grails 2.3.7.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to say for sure what is going wrong. I provided an answer below which includes a link to a project which uses the same nested param structure that you describe and the binding appears to work there.  If there is some detail you can change about that app which will trigger the problem, feel free to send a pull request or describe the change here and I can take a look.

Comment: Thanks Jeff - I'm just trying your project out now. I'm going to see if it hits the line of code that's blowing up for me in `GrailsDataBinder`

Comment: I had overlooked that you were using `GrailsDataBinder`.  That is the old Spring based binder.  Is there a reason you are using the Spring binder instead of the newer Grails binder?  That may be the significant difference between your app and the demo below.  The Spring binder is no longer maintained or supported.  It was left in Grails 2.3.x for backward compatibility.

Comment: We started developing our application with Grails 2.2. When we upgraded to 2.3, we found that a lot of things broke when we tried to use the new data binder. It's just one of the many things we haven't got around to addressing yet...

Comment: Yep, when I switch your demo project to using the legacy binder, I can reproduce the same issue I'm seeing in our application. I guess maybe now's a good time to look at upgrading...

Comment: I haven't tested your scenario with the old binder but if it doesn't work there, it is unlikely to be fixed at this point.  The new binder has evolved quite a bit since its release and there aren't many outstanding issues with it.  You should look at upgrading to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the sample app at https://github.com/jeffbrown/embeddedcollectionbinding.  That is a Grails 2.3.7 app which demonstrates one way to manage binding nested collections.  The following test uses the same nested parameter structure that you described, and the test passes:

```
// test/unit/demo/DemoControllerSpec.groovy
package demo

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(DemoController)
@Mock([Entry, Sale, ProductLineItem, Product])
class DemoControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void "test something"() {
        given:
        def product = new Product(code: 'initial product code').save()

        when:
        params.'sale.description' = 'some sale'
        params.'sale.productLineItems[0].product.id' = product.id
        params.'sale.productLineItems[0].name' = 'updated product name'
        params.'sale.productLineItems[0].description' = 'updated product description'
        def model = controller.createEntry()
        def entry = model.entry

        then:
        entry
        entry.sale
        entry.sale.description == 'some sale'
        entry.sale.productLineItems[0] instanceof ProductLineItem
        entry.sale.productLineItems[0].name == 'updated product name'
        entry.sale.productLineItems[0].description == 'updated product description'
        entry.sale.productLineItems[0].product
        entry.sale.productLineItems[0].product.code == 'initial product code'
    }
}
```

If there is some other detail in your model that complicates this, if you can provide any more detail I will be happy to help if I can.

I hope that helps.

Comment: As described in the comments below the initial question, this scenario works and is supported with the newer data binder that was introduced with Grails 2.3 and does not work with the deprecated legacy binder.  The legacy binder is no longer maintained and I do not anticipate we would look into this and fix it at this point.  The way forward is to use the new data binder as shown in the demo app linked above.